# Exposing a webserver not listening on port 80

Tags: web, port, server

My question is probably trivial and a duplicate, but either I cannot formulate it or it's not been answered on SO yet.

I have two webservers on a Digital Ocean droplet. One is listening on port `80` and can be accessed via `example.com` (DNS are on route 53), and the other is on port `8080`: how can I make it accessible from `example-2.com`?

I suppose the software I'm looking for would intercept the HTTP requests, check the referrer, and route those coming from `example.com` to port `80` and those coming from `example-2.com` to port `8080`. What is it?

Comment: You might be able to do this with a reverse proxy, but in general you cannot have two different processes listening on the same TCP/IP port.

Comment: OK so the reverse proxy would listen to everything on port 80, and redirect to the rest of the services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can not be done using only DNS.  By default web browsers attempt to connect to port 80 when the url starts with "http" without specifying a port.  The user would have to know to connect to port 8080 and explicitly access the URL as

```
http://example-2.com:8080
```

I am assuming you are running both web server instances on the same OS environment/IP address, though this would also work for separate hosting environments.  What you probably want is a reverse web proxy which can inspect the requested domain name and route to an appropriate server instance.  You would run the reverse web proxy on port 80, and probably move the server you are currently running on port 80 to another port (say, 8081).

Apache with mod_proxy and the virtual hosting settings is a possible solution.  Assuming example.com and example-2.com point to the Apache instance configure it something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName example.com
     ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com

     ProxyRequests off
     ProxyPreserveHost on
     ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8081/
     <Proxy *>
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
     </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName example-2.com
     ServerAdmin webmaster@example-2.com

     ProxyRequests off
     ProxyPreserveHost on
     ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
     <Proxy *>
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
     </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: this worked; careful, there is a `/` missing from the second VirtualHost after `:8080`

Comment: Sorry about that.  Also you might want to consider your firewall configuration (or which interfaces your web servers are configured to host from).  Users don't need to access :8080 and :8081 directly with this configuration (the proxy does it on their behalf) so I suggest locking those ports down to just the proxy server (in this case probably localhost).